# What is the point of GraphQL's ID Scalar?

Tags: graphql

https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types

I have read the description

> **`ID`**: The ID scalar type represents a unique identifier, often used to refetch an object or as the key for a cache. The ID type is serialized in the same way as a String; however, defining it as an **`ID`** signifies that it is not intended to be human‐readable.

But in practice, what actually changes if I use `ID` instead of `String` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing changes as it is mentioned in the description. `ID` is serialized exactly the same as `String` type; therefore, if you were to replace `ID` with `String`, computer would see no difference in it.

However, what is important to you is that YOU as a programmer know for sure that it's a unique identifier which will be useful when you paginate records, modify apollo cache, iteratively create jsx components.

So in practice, it has a very practical implication - it conveys important meaning for the programmer that the field is unique for the type.