# What is the best practice to use the Apollo cache identify method?

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

Based on the official docs Apollo's cache [identify](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#obtaining-an-objects-cache-id) method is used to get the id of the cache item because this ID could be custom and composed from different fields. That's clear.

To do it we need to receive an item from the cache to pass this item into the `cache.identify` and receive this item ID.

To get a cache item we have the next possibilities, based on the docs:

1. **[readQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#readquery)**.

```
const READ_TODO = gql`
  query ReadTodo($id: ID!) {
    todo(id: $id) {
      id
      text
      completed
    }
  }
`;

// Fetch the cached to-do item with ID 5
const { todo } = client.readQuery({
   query: READ_TODO,
   variables: {
     id: 5,
   },
 });
```

2. [**readFragment**](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#readfragment)

```
const todo = client.readFragment({
  id: 'Todo:5', // The value of the to-do item's cache ID
  fragment: gql`
    fragment MyTodo on Todo {
      id
      text
      completed
    }
  `,
});
```

These methods will return an item from the cache that we further could pass into the `cache.identify` to receive the ID. 
But they require the ID so it *must be known* at the moment of the execution of any of them.

So I'm wondering what is the best practice to use the **cache.identify** ?

So far I know, probably, it could be the only 1 use-case. 
 Obtain the possible cache item id in the [**update**](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations#the-update-function) callback that could be used as an option for a mutation that only updates an *existing* item. The backend could return a response with the modified object and it's possible to pass this object into the `cache.identify` to get the ID and pass it further into the appropriated cache update method. But I'm not sure if I'm right so would like to clarify it with more experienced Apollo developers. 
Is this the only 1 purpose for the **cache.identify** method?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That is what the docs say: `https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#obtaining-an-objects-cache-id`. Consider it as reading/writing into a DB. You can't read a single document without an id unless you reading randomly.

Answer (score 0):

So the first method doesn't actually require the cache ID.

As you mentioned, the cache ID can be customised based on your configuration. By default it uses the `__typename` and the `id`. So in your example it will be `Todo:5`.

Let's assume that your cache ID is based on the fields `[id, completed]`. The cache ID will look like `Todo:{"id": "idFromBackEnd", "completed": true}`. [More here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#customizing-cache-ids).

The `readFragment` function requires this cache ID. [More here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#readfragment).

But when you use `readQuery`, it doesn't need the cache ID but just a string that you used to query your back-end. The `ID` from the line `query ReadTodo($id: ID!)` is a scalar which is actually the same as a `String`, it just helps us as developers to know that we should expect it to be unique. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034752/what-is-the-point-of-graphqls-id-scalar).

So with the result of the `readQuery` you could use the `cache.identify` to find the exact cache ID.

So it will look something like this:

```
 const { todo } = client.readQuery({
   query: READ_TODO,
   variables: {
     id: 5,
   },
 });

const todoFragment = client.readFragment({
  id: client.cache.identify(todo) // it will figure out the cache Id,
  fragment: gql`
    fragment MyTodo on Todo {
      id
      text
      completed
    }
  `,
});
```

The purpose of the `cache.identify` is strictly to find a cache ID based on an object. The object could come from anywhere in your app. In our example we just picked it from a query result.

I hope this clarifies things a bit!